# Next.js project doesn't open on port 3000 when binding packages with Lerna

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lerna

I made a simple project using Lerna and Next.js. On packages I have project1 (Next.js project) and components (react project with button component).
When I run `lerna run dev` I can see project1 on localhost:3000, but when I link project1 with components, run `lerna run bootstrap` and after all i run `lerna run dev` again, the project1 is not started anymore, I can't see it on localhost:3000.

project1 -> package.json

```
  {
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@brunamendes/components": "^0.0.0",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6"
  }
}
```

components -> package.json

```
{
  "name": "@brunamendes/components",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "> TODO: description",
  "author": "brunamendes-02 <bruna.kcn@gmail.com>",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "__tests__"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: run tests from root\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "microbundle watch --jsx React.createElement lib/*.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.15.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0"
  },
  "source": "lib/index.js"
}
```

**Github project link** https://github.com/brunamendes-02/testing-lerna-config